# Permission to read all files that are not create by the app on android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

So I am already using the settings below

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

The problem is that with the new android version, I am not able to read files that are not created by my app due to security reason and that should be right.

But I know that there exist a way to ask the user to give the app permission to read those files on android.

Dose anyone know which permission I do need ?

> Update

Ok I read that `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` could solve the issue, dose anyone know how to ask for permission for that as `PermissionsAndroid` dose not have it.

Comment: Have a look at MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and further. Further: open a special settings page.

Comment: Yes found this now, I am looking on how to use it on react-native